# Table: One column take least space and the rest share the remaining space

Tags: javascript, html, css

Let's say I have X amount columns in a table. These are dynamic. I want the first one to take the least space.

This is easily done with:

```
td:first-child {
  width: 1%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Great. But how do I make the other columns share the remaining space?

```
td {
  &:not(:first-child) {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

This does not work. Do I have to use JavaScript or is it achievable with CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using JavaScript anyways. Find how many columns there is and divide it evenly. Most important thing is that you use

```
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not necessary:

```
td {
  &:not(:first-child) {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

I made a snippet without it and it works fine.

Is this what you needed?

```css
table.blueTable {
  border: 1px solid #1C6EA4;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table.blueTable td, table.blueTable th {
  border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
  padding: 3px 2px;
}
table.blueTable tbody td {
  font-size: 13px;
}
table.blueTable tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #D0E4F5;
}
table.blueTable thead {
  background: #1C6EA4;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #5592bb 0%, #327cad 66%, #1C6EA4 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #5592bb 0%, #327cad 66%, #1C6EA4 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #5592bb 0%, #327cad 66%, #1C6EA4 100%);
  border-bottom: 2px solid #444444;
}
table.blueTable thead th {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border-left: 2px solid #D0E4F5;
}
/*Your code*/

td:first-child {
  width: 1%;
}

/*My code*/
.specialTd{
    width: 1%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<table class="blueTable">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>head1</th>
<th>head2</th>
<th>head3</th>
<th>head4</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>cell1_1</td>
<td>cell2_1</td>
<td class="specialTd">cell3_1cell3_1cell3_1cell3_1cell3_1cell3_cell3_1cell3_1cell3_1cell3_1</td>
<td>cell4_1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>cell1_2</td>
<td>cell2_2</td>
<td>cell3_2</td>
<td>cell4_2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>cell1_3</td>
<td>cell2_3</td>
<td>cell3_3</td>
<td>cell4_3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>cell1_4</td>
<td>cell2_4</td>
<td>cell3_4</td>
<td>cell4_4</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Following your comment:

> Right, but this only works since each column has the same content width. Let's say column 3 has a progress bar that wants to take more space than the other columns. How do you fix that?

You have to specify which `td` you have to make it take more space than the others. In the above snippet I use the class `specialTd`.

The magic is in the css property   `white-space: nowrap;` which sets how white space inside an element is handled.

More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space).

Remember that you have to set a minimum amount of width to make it works, that becasue I added `width: 1%;` to my `specialTd` class.

Comment: Right, but this only works since each column has the same content width. Let's say column 3 has a progress bar that wants to take more space than the other columns. How do you fix that?

Comment: Martin, now if you look at your solution, you see that column "head3" takes the most space. I want it head2, head3 and head4 to have the same width.

Comment: Ok, so what you want is: when column3 wants to take more space than the other columns you want to column2 and 4 take the same space?

Comment: Precisely. I ended using JavaScript if you look at my answer.